question about user-specific databases while using a telegram bot
im a beginner and i've been trying to make my own telegram bot and i have a question:
how do i ask the user for input(specifically when clicking a button) and transfer the input in a data base specific to the user(so its not a data base with all of the users' data) but then allow the user to edit and access the data in the form of a table/file?
im using aiogram and thought of somehow directing data straight to excel and then sending the user a link specifically to a table with their data. would using sqlite be easier? my idea was to make something similar to how @Migrebot uses a 'diary' and allows the user to export their data as a xlsx file.
